# Design of DevExpress Form can not load

Tags: winforms, devexpress

When I try to open xtraform design I get some kind of that error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'nanodems.NDIS.MessageParser, Version=1.0.9.436, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified."
```

But I am using the specified version of dll! I could not figure out the reason of the problem. What is the problem?

Comment: Does it occure only in this project, or event in a new project ?

Comment: I only faced this problem on this project.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Check the project references, may be the project reference his own Dll, if it's true, delete the refernce.

Comment: I have a project named BO and I use dll of BO as reference in a map project and in this map project I get the "wrong version of BO dll".

Comment: Can the commonassembly file cause this problem?